# Wordpress PHP Call MySQL Procedure is hanging

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My procedure is described below, but my problem is that the procedure works successfully when executed via phpmyAdmin, but if called from within Wordpress directly it hangs.

I have identified that any attempt to include a loop (REPEAT, WHILE etc.) in the procedure causes it to hang when called from wordpress (ref 1st procedure with REPEAT loop, second without). Any suggestions to fix this is my question as I need to be able to loop for every date between 2 dates for a given frequency, monthly, weekly etc.

I have defined a MySQL procedure (shown below) to insert a schedule of direct debit payments a row for every date a payment is made, as follows.

I have defined a Wordpress Plugin PHP Snippet to call the procedure, which is called using a shortcode defined using Elementor page builder.

e.g.
**Direct Debit Header Table**

```
Name,        Date From,  Date To,    Frequency (M)onthly etc., Amount
SWW Water,   12/11/2018, 12/11/2019, M, £50.00
```

**Schedule Table**

```
Name,      PaymentDate Amount
SWW Water, 12/11/2018, £50.00
SWW Water, 12/12/2018, £50.00
etc. to
SWW Water, 12/11/2020, £50.00
```

**PROCEDURE InsertScheduleRows**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE currdate    DATE;
DECLARE enddate     DATE;
DECLARE userid      CHARACTER;
DECLARE codearg     CHARACTER;
DECLARE frequency   CHARACTER;

SELECT *, 
    @currdate   := DATE_FORMAT(transactiondd.date_from, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
    @enddate    := DATE_FORMAT(transactiondd.date_to, "%Y-%m-%d"),
    @frequency  := transactiondd.frequency,
    @codearg    := transactiondd.code,
    @userid     := transactiondd.user_id

FROM
  transactiondd
WHERE 
    updated = 'n';

SET currdate    = @currdate;
SET enddate     = @enddate;
SET codearg     = @codearg;
SET userid      = @userid;
SET frequency   = @frequency;

DELETE FROM 
    scheduledd
WHERE
    code    = @codearg
AND
    user_id = @userid;

REPEAT

SELECT currdate;

INSERT INTO scheduledd
( code, name, paydate, amount, user_id, account_id, transactiondd_id ) 
SELECT code, name, `currdate`, amount, `userid`, account_id, id 
FROM 
    transactiondd
WHERE 
    updated = 'n';
CASE frequency
    WHEN 'D' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    WHEN 'W' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 7 DAY);
    WHEN 'M' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    WHEN 'Q' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 QUARTER);
    WHEN 'A' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
END CASE;

UNTIL currdate > enddate 

END REPEAT;    
END
```

Once working I need to add code to the procedure to update the transactiondd.updated flag to 'y' on a successful insert of rows into the scheduledd table

**Wordpress Plugin PHP Snippet Costs Schedule Update**

```
global $wpdb;    
   $result = $wpdb->get_results("
    CALL
    `InsertScheduleRows`()
");                           

print_r($result);
```

The above plugin is called using a shortcode of the form

**[wbcr_php_snippet id="14613"]**

Thanks in advance for any help.

**This procedure works for one date only now that I have omitted the REPEAT UNTIL END REPEAT lines **

so it appears the hanging is todo with those lines !!

```
BEGIN

DECLARE currdate    DATE;
DECLARE enddate     DATE;
DECLARE userid      CHARACTER;
DECLARE codearg     CHARACTER;
DECLARE frequency   CHARACTER;

SELECT *, 
    @currdate   := DATE_FORMAT(dm_transactiondd.date_from, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
    @enddate    := DATE_FORMAT(dm_transactiondd.date_to, "%Y-%m-%d"),
    @frequency  := dm_transactiondd.frequency,
    @codearg    := dm_transactiondd.code,
    @userid     := dm_transactiondd.user_id

FROM
  dm_transactiondd
WHERE 
    updated = 'n';

SET currdate    = @currdate;
SET enddate     = @enddate;
SET codearg     = @codearg;
SET userid      = @userid;
SET frequency   = @frequency;

DELETE FROM 
    dm_scheduledd
WHERE
    code    = @codearg
AND
    user_id = @userid;

INSERT INTO dm_scheduledd
(code,name,type_id,paydate,amount,user_id,account_id,transactiondd_id) 
SELECT code, name, type_id, `currdate`, amount, `userid`, account_id,id 
FROM
    dm_transactiondd
WHERE 
    updated = 'n';

CASE frequency
    WHEN 'D' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    WHEN 'W' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 7 DAY);
    WHEN 'M' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    WHEN 'Q' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 QUARTER);
    WHEN 'A' THEN SET currdate = DATE_ADD(currdate,INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
END CASE;
END
```

Colin

Comment: I can confirm that from testing the section of the procedure before REPEAT command works without hanging, so the section from REPEAT onwards is responsible for the hang, I am a novice at procedure programming so it may be a simple error in the code, I know the delete section only works for a single row returned by the SELECT Colin

Comment: Update: I have deleted the lines REPEAT and END REPEAT; lines from the above PROCEDURE, the result is that the procedure no longer hangs, displays empty Array () when run within wordpress. Running from phpmyadmin it writes one record / row (as expected, required) out to the scheduledd table. Have added this comment to main section, Colin

Comment: I have updated the main content above with the latest update

Comment: The procedure is hanging on the REPEAT loop, I have tried a WHILE LOOP and the procedure times out at 60 seconds in both cases through wordpress, but runs ok on phpmyadmin. Also although the system hangs it makes the insert of rows correctly. Colin

Comment: If, as you say,  the procedure is working properly in phpMyAdmin, than it is possible that it is a permissions issue. [link]https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20221/mysql-user-permission-on-stored-procedure

Comment: You may want to try  **$wpdb->query("CALL InsertScheduleRows()");**   instead of **$wpdb->get_results** in your shortcode function as well ...

Comment: Hi Jamie_D, thanks for your comments, unfortunately the CALL option above still results in hanging or timeout, 60 seconds. I am on a shared server so I cannot change the access permissions. I realise I may however in time have to move to a dedicated server ?. any other suggestions please let me know Thanks Colin